# Can I include the week number in a datetime value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataset the includes a 'Year', 'Week' and 'Date' column. The Year and Week are redundant so I'm going to drop them, however I wanted to know if it was possible to include the week number within the `datetime` values currently formatted as `%YYYY-%MM-%DD-%hh-%mm-%ss`. I'm basically going for something like `%YYYY-%MM-%WW-%DD-%hh-%mm-%ss`. For example, I'm currently working with:

| Year | Week | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 01 | 2021-01-01-00-00-01 |
| 2021 | 02 | 2021-01-08-00-00-01 |

But I'm trying to drop the 'Year' and Week' columns giventhat info is in the 'Date' column. It's no issue with the year since the `datetime` format already includes year, but I also want it to include the week number to have something like 2021-01-02-08-00-00-01 in the second row. Basically the final table should look like:

| Date |
| --- |
| 2021-01-02-08-00-00-01 |

Comment: please provide an example of the data (as text) and the matching expected output

Comment: i don't understand - do you want to `parse input string` or `format output string`? What did you try? What error did you get? Better show example code with example data and expected result. And always show FULL error message. And put it all in question (not in comments)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropping the unwanted columns:

```
df = df.drop(columns=['Year', 'Week'])
```

Formatting the date:

Use [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to format the date (see the [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) documentation as reference for the format, in particulat `%U` for the week number)

```
# format to %YYYY-%MM-%DD-%WW-%hh-%mm-%ss
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%U-%H-%M-%S')
```

output:

```
                     Date
0  2021-01-01-00-00-00-00
1  2021-01-08-01-00-00-00
```

*NB. I formatted to `%YYYY-%MM-%DD-%WW-%hh-%mm-%ss`, (not `%YYYY-%MM-%WW-%DD-%hh-%mm-%ss`) to match the provided output, but its easy enough to change if `%YYYY-%MM-%WW-%DD-%hh-%mm-%ss` is really what you need, just swap `%d` and `%U`*